# samba - permission denied when share in another users home directory

Tags: permissions, samba

I have the two users `equah` and `hoster` on my machine.

I created a samba share `test1` in `/home/equah`, which is accessible by user `equah` without any problem.

I also created the share `test2` in `/smbtest` and changed ownership to user `equah`, which is accessible by `equah` too.

But when I create the share `test3` in `/home/hoster/sharetest` and try to connect, nautilus prompts with `Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied`, which is what i would like to get working.

`ls -l` shows the following details on the described directories:

```
drwx------ 14 equah equah 4096 Sep  8 20:09 /home/equah
drwxr-xr-x 2 equah equah 4096 Sep  8 20:33 /smbtest
drwxrwxrwx 3 equah equah 4096 Sep  8 20:44 /home/hoster/sharetest
drwx------ 19 hoster hoster 4096 Sep  8 20:20 /home/hoster
```

I also saw, that Access Control System applied permissions on the `hoster` home directory, which I removed to see if this was the error, but without any success.

I currently use a fresh Arch Linux installation with `samba 4.8.5-1`.

My samba configuration (`/etc/samba/smb.conf`) contains:

```
[global]
   workgroup = EQGROUP
   server string = eq-host samba server
   server role = standalone server
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   max log size = 50
   dns proxy = no 

[test1]
   comment = test
   path = /home/equah
   valid users = equah

[test2]
   comment = test
   path = /smbtest
   valid users = equah

[test3] # <== Not Working ?
   comment = test
   path = /home/hoster/sharetest
   valid users = equah
```

My toughs are, that some permission settings might prevent the logged in samba user from accessing content of a directory from which any parent directory is owned by another user. Tough creating a share in `/home/hoster/sharetest/test` and changing ownership of both `sharetest/test` to equah, does also not work to share only the `test` folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got a classic ownership/permissions problem here. You've told SAMBA to allow access to `/home/hoster/sharetest` only to `equah` but your underlying filesystem permissions deny  access to that user (`drwx------ 19 hoster hoster 4096 Sep  8 20:20 /home/hoster`).

Allow `equah` access to the directory and it should be ok

```
chmod a+x /home/hoster
```

Or force the access by `equah` to be performed by `hoster`

```
# add to smb.conf share definition
force user = hoster
```

In general this kind of problem can be diagnosed using `log level = 3` and looking in the SAMBA server log files.

Comment: thanks for advising `log level = 3`!